# What does "X is not a four-letter word" mean?

Tags: phrases, idioms, offensive-language

Once in a while I see phrases like [*"Think" is not a four-letter word*](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/big-picture.html#faq-6.16) and just about any word can be where "think" is.

[I looked up the Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-letter_word) and looks like it says that "four-letter word" means slang words with mostly negative meaning.

What does "four-letter word" mean here? Does it mean something like "it's not that bad to think once in a while"?

Comment: This should be obvious, but it is a pun.  As other people have already explained, “four-letter word” in this context means something to avoid.  At the same time, “think” consists of five letters, not four.

Comment: [Insert four letter word here.]

Comment: a four-letter word is an unabbreviated form of f**k

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Idiomatically a *four-letter word* is a swearword, considered rude and unacceptable in certain contexts.

The implication is here is that *thinking* and coming up with original solutions to problems is not to be frowned upon in the same way, and indeed is acceptable and encouraged.

Answer (score 5):

It simply means "[X] is not a swear word."

The implication is that you have been avoiding [X], and the speaker is assigning a (highly unlikely, as the speaker is well aware) cause to that avoidance. As such, it's a form of hyperbole.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "four-letter word" is used to refer to one of the many offensive slang words in the English language containing four letters.

Usually the word *fuck* is intended or implied but there are many others, as listed by Wikipedia in your link. Again, from your Wikipedia link we learn that other languages have a similar term, sometimes referring to three or five letters depending on the language and its key swear words.

To say something *is not a four-letter word* is often used humorously or to provoke thought, since the author is suggesting that the something should *not* be considered especially bad. Often the something isn't commonly thought to be bad at all, hence the mild humour.

Comment: It's funnier when the word is in fact spelled with four letters, though. Like, say, `goto`.

Comment: @SamB [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/292/)

Comment: @SamB: Using `goto` in computer programming is considered bad practice (and in modern programming languages well hidden or not possible). So this would by many programmers actually fall into the category of _four letter word_ also in the meaning of being a swear word...

Answer (score 1):

There is a popular song by the band [Cake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cake_%28band%29) called **Friend Is a Four Letter Word** on their album *Fashion Nugget*.

Excerpt:

```
 But to me, coming from you,
"Friend" is a four-letter word,
"End" is the only part of the word
 That I heard...
 Call me morbid, or absurd,

 But to me, coming from you,
"Friend" is a four-letter word.
```

(Mostly unrelated, but as the question has already been answered I thought it was an interesting example)

Comment: I also thought of the same song; the implied “let's stay friends from now on” that the other party has said clears a little the “But to me, coming from you, "friend" is a four-letter word”.

Comment: @TZ: I don't exactly understand your comment.

Comment: As you say, this is mostly unrelated and would be better as a comment.